# initWithObjectsAndKeys for JSON POST to MySQL via PHP - gets empty rows in DB

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, ios, json

Like the title says..

My NSDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys for JSON, with the POST method, to do MySQL query via PHP code, by using the json_encoding and json_decoding creates empty data in my SQL database, just the ID int is auto increasing every time I post!

My Xcode code:

```
-(IBAction)setJsonFromData:(id)sender
{
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Welcome", @"title", @"Hello", @"article", @"123456789", @"timestamp", nil];

    if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:jsonDict])
        {
           NSError *error = nil;
           NSData *result = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict     options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
           if (error == nil && result != nil) {
           [self postJSONtoURL:result];
        }
    }
}

-(id)postJSONtoURL:(NSData *)requestJSONdata
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.com/json.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestJSONdata length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestJSONdata];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", requestJSONdata);

    if (error == nil)
        return result;
    return nil;
}
```

My PHP code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST))
{
    $json = $_REQUEST;
    $data = json_decode($json);

    $title = $_REQUEST['title'];
    $article = $_REQUEST['article'];
    $timestamp = $_REQUEST['timestamp'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (title, article, timestamp) VALUES ('$title->title','$article->article','$timestamp->timestamp')");
}

mysql_close();
```

Comment: My NSLog printing out the posted jsonDict using Breakpoints:

`po jsonDict
(NSDictionary *) $1 = 0x07569fb0 {
    article = Hello;
    timestamp = 123456789;
    title = Welcome;
}`

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/). Also your code has significant security concerns.

Comment: Nice [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d. You have no error handling on both the json decode or query call, assuming that everything worked perfectly. Since it obviously isn't, you should add some errorhandling/debug statements in there.

Comment: This isnt my code @Jason-McCreary I just used and edited it from web, I dont work with PHP, still learning, I just do iOS and I am still learning aswell so.. :)

Comment: @emotality, I appreciate that you are learning. But the code smells whether it's yours or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving the json payload in the http body since you do a POST request.
So, you'll need to decode that:

```
$http_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($http_body);
```

After that you should be able to access data like:

```
$data->title
```

PHP does not automatically decode incoming json data.

see the [docs](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/wrappers.php.php) regarding that `php://input` thing.

Comment: This worked!! Thanks man, very quick response and accurate :)

Didnt know about the http body, learning everyday ;)

Comment: Glad to help. `$_REQUEST` is an array which combines `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`. These are provided by php and only contain query string parameters (and cookies). see the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) ;)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that your not getting any data to your php file.

when you do a post request, you need to do

$whatevervar = $_POST['NAME-OF-POST-VARIABLE-FROM-CLIENT'] thats why you are posting empty stuff in your database. and when you post into your db do not directly put the post variables in there, first clean and strip the post, then put the second var into your db. also you need to have a response call back to know what happened with your query.